# Multiple total in Dynamic Pivot

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, join, sum, dynamic-pivot

I have been struggling with a MSSQL Server query for the past 4 days. Whatever I tried I failed. If its possible can I get hand here.

This is the report I want to take from query:

```
          Playstation    Laptop    Phone    Macbook    Total 
-------------------------------------------------------------
England    1x 257$       0x 0$     0x 0$     0x 0$    1x 257$
Sweden     0x 0$         1x 433$   1x 424$   0x 0$    2x 857$ 
Russia     2x 472$       0x 0$     0x 0$     0x 0$    2x 472$
Italy      0x 0$         0x 0$     0x 0$     0x 0$    0x 0$
Total      3x 729$       1x 433$   1x 424$   0x 0$    5x 1586$
```

These are my tables:

`Country` table:

```
Id   Name   
----------------------------------------
1     England
2     Sweden
3     Russia
4     Italy
```

`Items` table:

```
Id   Name   
----------------------------------------
1     Laptop
2     Phone
3     Playstation
4     Macbook
```

`Pre-Request` table:

```
Id   countryId   ItemId      blablabla
----------------------------------------
1        1         3          blablabla 
2        2         1          blablabla 
3        2         2          blablabla 
4        3         3          blablabla 
5        3         3          blablabla 
6        2         3          blablabla
```

`Offers` table:

```
Id   Price         Blablabla
----------------------------------------
18     257$          Blablabla
19     151$          Blablabla
20     424$          Blablabla
21     433$          Blablabla
22     321$          Blablabla
```

`Request` table:

```
Id     preReqId     requestStatus     winOfferId
---------------------------------------------
44        1          3                   18
11        2          4                   21
53        3          4                   20
87        4          3                   22
43        5          3                   19
45        6          2                   Null
```

Blablabla columns and rows don't matter. Only catch with reporting table query is I must use `requestStatus > 2` to take legit report and even there is no order from "Italy" or no order for "Macbook" they will be  in report anyway. Thank you

Comment: From which table name of the country should select?

Comment: All countries from "country" table, even if they null for example Id-4 Italy has no request or anything it ll come to report anyway, with 0x 0$ for all rows

Comment: Country with `Id=2` (Sweden) is associated with `ItemId=3` (playstation). Why is the corresponding price equal to 0 in the output?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos cuz at Request table its reuestStatus doenst bigger than 2, that means case in progress not completed.

Comment: And why is that? Which association leads to request with `Id=43`?

Comment: Never mind I just figured it out: `Id` of `Pre-Request` is associated with column `preReqId` of  `Request`, right?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos ye Its my bad Id=43 now unique, Its primary key for "Request" table

Comment: Why $321 - playstation, russia is not included in ur result even Italy is also added?

Comment: @SarathAvanavu Its added, 2 playstation sold for russia and at report its 2 piece and 321 + 151 so result  "2x 472$".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am inserting into a temporary table to make the query more readable. I have written the logic inside.

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT I.NAME ITEMNAME,C.NAME COUNTRYNAME
    ,CAST(REPLACE(TAB.PRICE,'$','')AS INT)PRICE
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN TAB.PRICE IS NOT NULL THEN I.NAME END) OVER(PARTITION BY C.NAME,I.NAME) CNTITEM    
    FROM [#Pre-Request] PR
    LEFT JOIN #Items I ON PR.ITEMID=I.ID
    LEFT JOIN #COUNTRY C ON PR.COUNTRYID = C.ID
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT R.preReqId,R.winOfferId,O.PRICE
        FROM #Request R 
        JOIN #Offers O ON R.winOfferId=O.Id
        WHERE PR.ID=R.preReqId
    )TAB
    
    UNION 
    -- Used to select Item name and country that are not in Pre-request table and other tables
    SELECT I.NAME ,C.NAME ,NULL,0
    FROM #Items I
    CROSS JOIN #COUNTRY C
)
,CTE2 AS
(
    -- Find the sum for number of items
    SELECT DISTINCT ISNULL(ITEMNAME,'TOTAL')ITEMNAME,ISNULL(COUNTRYNAME,'TOTAL')COUNTRYNAME,
    SUM(PRICE)PRICE 
    FROM CTE
    GROUP BY ITEMNAME,COUNTRYNAME
    WITH CUBE
)
,CTE3 AS
(
    -- Find the sum of PRICE
    SELECT DISTINCT ISNULL(ITEMNAME,'TOTAL')ITEMNAME,ISNULL(COUNTRYNAME,'TOTAL')COUNTRYNAME--,CNTITEM
    ,SUM(CNTITEM)CNTITEM    
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT ITEMNAME,COUNTRYNAME,CNTITEM
        FROM CTE
    )TAB
    GROUP BY ITEMNAME,COUNTRYNAME
    WITH CUBE
)
SELECT C2.*,C3.CNTITEM,
CAST(C3.CNTITEM AS VARCHAR(20))+'x'+' ' + CAST(C2.PRICE AS VARCHAR(20))+'$' NEWCOL
INTO #NEWTABLE
FROM CTE2 C2
JOIN CTE3 C3 ON C2.COUNTRYNAME=C3.COUNTRYNAME AND C2.ITEMNAME=C3.ITEMNAME
```

Get columns for dynamic pivot

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @cols = COALESCE (@cols + ',[' + ITEMNAME + ']', '[' + ITEMNAME + ']')
               FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ITEMNAME FROM #NEWTABLE WHERE ITEMNAME<>'TOTAL') PV 
               ORDER BY ITEMNAME 
-- Since we need Total in last column, we append it at last
SELECT @cols += ',[Total]'
```

Now pivot the query

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = 'SELECT COUNTRYNAME,' + @cols + ' FROM 
             (
                 SELECT DISTINCT ITEMNAME,COUNTRYNAME,ISNULL(NEWCOL,''0x 0$'')NEWCOL
                 FROM #NEWTABLE
             ) x
             PIVOT 
             (
                 MIN(NEWCOL)
                 FOR ITEMNAME IN (' + @cols + ')
            ) p
            ORDER BY CASE WHEN (COUNTRYNAME=''Total'') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,COUNTRYNAME' 

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

- **[Click here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/281097/pivot-with-row-and-total-on-varchar) to view result**

Comment: umm one more thing tho;
SELECT cols = COALESCE (cols + ',[' + ITEMNAME + ']', '[' + ITEMNAME + ']')
               FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ITEMNAME FROM #NEWTABLE WHERE ITEMNAME<>'TOTAL') PV 
               ORDER BY ITEMNAME   , can I order by "I.Id" instead of alphabetic "ITEMNAME"

Comment: Yes. You can. `SELECT cols = COALESCE (cols + ',[' + ITEMNAME + ']', '[' + ITEMNAME + ']') FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ID,ITEMNAME FROM #NEWTABLE WHERE ITEMNAME<>'TOTAL') PV ORDER BY ID` @TeknoBilSoft

Comment: Hello sir, I was using your query it  help a lot (thanks again), but needed to do some edits, now its broken. It still works but if items has same price even though it gives correct count of items but it distinct total price only add one to "sum" function. Can you quick look at it please ? @Sarath Avanavu

Comment: Actually I just figured out its been an error from beginning, Can you try to change "SELECT 22,'321$' " row from your query to SELECT 22,'151$'. (http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/281097/pivot-with-row-and-total-on-varchar) You will see it still counts 2x but only take sum price once to Total coloumb. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32412753/total-sum-wrong-value-in-dynamic-pivot