# Total sum wrong value in Dynamic Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, pivot, distinct

I have complicated query which works pretty good (MS SQL 2012). But it makes a mistake when sum up same price items. It count them correctly but only takes price once instead of taking them as a count number. It only appears when same item has same price and from same country. Here is my query ;

```
CREATE TABLE #ITEMS(ID INT,NAME VARCHAR(30))

INSERT INTO #ITEMS
SELECT 1,     'laptop'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,     'phone'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3,     'playstation'
UNION ALL
SELECT 4,     'MacBook'

CREATE TABLE #Country(ID INT,NAME VARCHAR(30))

INSERT INTO #Country
SELECT 1,     'England'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,     'Sweden'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3,     'Russia'
UNION ALL
SELECT 4,     'Italy'


CREATE TABLE [#Pre-Request](Id INT,  countryId INT,  ItemId INT) 

INSERT INTO [#Pre-Request]
SELECT 1,1,3
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,2,1
UNION ALL
SELECT 3,2,2
UNION ALL
SELECT 4,3,3
UNION ALL
SELECT 5,3,3
UNION ALL
SELECT 6,2,3

CREATE TABLE #Offers(Id INT,  PRICE VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO #Offers
SELECT 18,'257$'
UNION ALL
SELECT 19,'151$'
UNION ALL
SELECT 20,'424$'   
UNION ALL
SELECT 21,'433$'
UNION ALL
SELECT 22,'151$' 

CREATE TABLE #Request(Id INT,  preReqId INT,  requestStatus INT,winOfferId INT) 

INSERT INTO #Request
SELECT 44,        1,          3,                   18
UNION ALL
SELECT 11,        2,          4,                   21
UNION ALL
SELECT 53,        3,          4,                   20
UNION ALL
SELECT 87,        4,          3,                   22
UNION ALL
SELECT 43,        5,          3,                   19
UNION ALL
SELECT 43,        6,          2,                   Null




;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT I.NAME ITEMNAME,C.NAME COUNTRYNAME
    ,CAST(REPLACE(TAB.PRICE,'$','')AS INT)PRICE
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN TAB.PRICE IS NOT NULL THEN I.NAME END) OVER(PARTITION BY C.NAME,I.NAME) CNTITEM    
    FROM [#Pre-Request] PR
    LEFT JOIN #Items I ON PR.ITEMID=I.ID
    LEFT JOIN #COUNTRY C ON PR.COUNTRYID = C.ID
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT R.preReqId,R.winOfferId,O.PRICE
        FROM #Request R 
        JOIN #Offers O ON R.winOfferId=O.Id
        WHERE PR.ID=R.preReqId
    )TAB

    UNION 
    -- Used to select Item name and country that are not in Pre-request table and other tables
    SELECT I.NAME ,C.NAME ,NULL,0
    FROM #Items I
    CROSS JOIN #COUNTRY C
)
,CTE2 AS
(
    -- Find the sum for number of items
    SELECT DISTINCT ISNULL(ITEMNAME,'TOTAL')ITEMNAME,ISNULL(COUNTRYNAME,'TOTAL')COUNTRYNAME,
    SUM(PRICE)PRICE 
    FROM CTE
    GROUP BY ITEMNAME,COUNTRYNAME
    WITH CUBE
)
,CTE3 AS
(
    -- Find the sum of PRICE
    SELECT DISTINCT ISNULL(ITEMNAME,'TOTAL')ITEMNAME,ISNULL(COUNTRYNAME,'TOTAL')COUNTRYNAME--,CNTITEM
    ,SUM(CNTITEM)CNTITEM    
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT ITEMNAME,COUNTRYNAME,CNTITEM
        FROM CTE
    )TAB
    GROUP BY ITEMNAME,COUNTRYNAME
    WITH CUBE
)
SELECT C2.*,C3.CNTITEM,
CAST(C3.CNTITEM AS VARCHAR(20))+'x'+' ' + CAST(C2.PRICE AS VARCHAR(20))+'$' NEWCOL
INTO #NEWTABLE
FROM CTE2 C2
JOIN CTE3 C3 ON C2.COUNTRYNAME=C3.COUNTRYNAME AND C2.ITEMNAME=C3.ITEMNAME







DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @cols = COALESCE (@cols + ',[' + ITEMNAME + ']', '[' + ITEMNAME + ']')
               FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ITEMNAME FROM #NEWTABLE WHERE ITEMNAME<>'TOTAL') PV 
               ORDER BY ITEMNAME 
-- Since we need Total in last column, we append it at last
SELECT @cols += ',[Total]'


DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = 'SELECT COUNTRYNAME,' + @cols + ' FROM 
             (
                 SELECT DISTINCT ITEMNAME,COUNTRYNAME,ISNULL(NEWCOL,''0x 0$'')NEWCOL
                 FROM #NEWTABLE
             ) x
             PIVOT 
             (
                 MIN(NEWCOL)
                 FOR ITEMNAME IN (' + @cols + ')
            ) p
            ORDER BY CASE WHEN (COUNTRYNAME=''Total'') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,COUNTRYNAME' 

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

and here is result ;

[image]

As you can see there are 2 "playstation" from "Russia" it takes correct count (2x) but only take 1 price "151$" (normally it must be 302$). How can I fix this without making major changes from query? Thank you.

Comment: I check quickly your query and I think the problem is before Pivoting. Second storing in one column number of item x total price if counterintuitive for me. When I see `2x 302` I imagine 2 items per 302$ not 2 items with total cost 302, can't you store item number/sum of prices in two columns separate columns for each product and Total?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @lad2025 yes 2x means count of item number, not per price. And I need this values in one table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does what you want. The problem is in your first CTE where you do the item count and get a distinct on the ItemName, CountryName, and Price.

Instead of getting a distinct, do a group by as shown below and SUM the price.

```
    SELECT I.NAME ITEMNAME, C.NAME COUNTRYNAME
,SUM(CAST(REPLACE(TAB.PRICE,'$','')AS INT))PRICE
,COUNT(CASE WHEN TAB.PRICE IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) CNTITEM    
FROM [#Pre-Request] PR
LEFT JOIN #Items I ON PR.ITEMID=I.ID
LEFT JOIN #COUNTRY C ON PR.COUNTRYID = C.ID
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT R.preReqId,R.winOfferId,O.PRICE
    FROM #Request R 
    JOIN #Offers O ON R.winOfferId=O.Id
    WHERE PR.ID=R.preReqId
)TAB
GROUP BY
    I.NAME 
    ,C.NAME
```

EDIT:
Here are the results I get:

[image]

Here's all of your code starting from the CTEs:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT I.NAME ITEMNAME, C.NAME COUNTRYNAME
    ,SUM(CAST(REPLACE(TAB.PRICE,'$','')AS INT))PRICE
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN TAB.PRICE IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) CNTITEM    
    FROM [#Pre-Request] PR
    LEFT JOIN #Items I ON PR.ITEMID=I.ID
    LEFT JOIN #COUNTRY C ON PR.COUNTRYID = C.ID
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT R.preReqId,R.winOfferId,O.PRICE
        FROM #Request R 
        JOIN #Offers O ON R.winOfferId=O.Id
        WHERE PR.ID=R.preReqId
    )TAB
    GROUP BY
        I.NAME 
        ,C.NAME

    UNION 
    -- Used to select Item name and country that are not in Pre-request table and other tables
    SELECT I.NAME ,C.NAME ,NULL,0
    FROM #Items I
    CROSS JOIN #COUNTRY C
)
,CTE2 AS
(
    -- Find the sum for number of items
    SELECT DISTINCT ISNULL(ITEMNAME,'TOTAL')ITEMNAME,ISNULL(COUNTRYNAME,'TOTAL')COUNTRYNAME,
    SUM(PRICE)PRICE 
    FROM CTE
    GROUP BY ITEMNAME,COUNTRYNAME
    WITH CUBE
)
,CTE3 AS
(
    -- Find the sum of PRICE
    SELECT DISTINCT ISNULL(ITEMNAME,'TOTAL')ITEMNAME,ISNULL(COUNTRYNAME,'TOTAL')COUNTRYNAME--,CNTITEM
    ,SUM(CNTITEM)CNTITEM    
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT ITEMNAME,COUNTRYNAME,CNTITEM
        FROM CTE
    )TAB
    GROUP BY ITEMNAME,COUNTRYNAME
    WITH CUBE
)

SELECT C2.*,C3.CNTITEM,
CAST(C3.CNTITEM AS VARCHAR(20))+'x'+' ' + CAST(C2.PRICE AS VARCHAR(20))+'$' NEWCOL
INTO #NEWTABLE
FROM CTE2 C2
JOIN CTE3 C3 ON C2.COUNTRYNAME=C3.COUNTRYNAME AND C2.ITEMNAME=C3.ITEMNAME







DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @cols = COALESCE (@cols + ',[' + ITEMNAME + ']', '[' + ITEMNAME + ']')
               FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ITEMNAME FROM #NEWTABLE WHERE ITEMNAME<>'TOTAL') PV 
               ORDER BY ITEMNAME 
-- Since we need Total in last column, we append it at last
SELECT @cols += ',[Total]'


DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = 'SELECT COUNTRYNAME,' + @cols + ' FROM 
             (
                 SELECT DISTINCT ITEMNAME,COUNTRYNAME,ISNULL(NEWCOL,''0x 0$'')NEWCOL
                 FROM #NEWTABLE
             ) x
             PIVOT 
             (
                 MIN(NEWCOL)
                 FOR ITEMNAME IN (' + @cols + ')
            ) p
            ORDER BY CASE WHEN (COUNTRYNAME=''Total'') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,COUNTRYNAME' 

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

Comment: now it gives "604$" and other values coming wrong aswell ?

Comment: I added the results I'm getting and the whole code block. I don't see $604 coming back in my results.